# программа которая находит в текстовом файле слово с наибольшем количеством букв А и выводит его на экран

Tags: c++, строки, файлы

Пожалуйста, помогите понять как реализовать это в программе

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string path = "myFile.txt";
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(path);
    string str;
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
      str="";  
      getline(fin,str);
      cout<<str<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: забудьте  про  while (!fin.eof()).... про это достаточно было сказано уже. Да и потом вы должны находить слово, а не строку....

Answer (score 1):

1. Вы можете сразу определить и открыть `std::ifstream fin("myFile.txt")`
2. кроме строки `std::string str`, которую вы будете читать, нужна еще
   одна строка, куда вы запишете нужное слово:  `std::string_view result("wasn't found")`. Тут строка на случай, если не будет ни одного слова с данным символом.
3. Вы должны где то хранить и  количество данного символа в слове:
   `size_t max_number = 0`

Дальше просто считывать слова и считать количество символа в них:

```
while (fin >> str)
{
    size_t k = 0;
    for (char c : str) {
        if (toupper(c) == 'A')
            ++k;
    }
    if (max_number < k) {
        max_number = k;
        result = str;
    }
}
```

И вывести `result`

Это вся логика, но реализовывать можно разными способами, в том числе и с помощью std::set и std::map. Будет  еще уместна проверка на открытие файла. После того, как был прочтен весь текст, маркер конца файла не будет установлен, поэтому проверка на fin.eof() ошибочна. Это состояние можно проверить только в цикле, но тут такой нужды нет.

Comment: `std::string_view result`. После привязки `result` к строке `str` очередная итерация цикла `while` перезапишет строку `str` и, следовательно, инвалидирует значение в `result`. Ну и аргумент функции `toupper` нужно конвертировать в `unsigned char`, иначе возможно UB при передаче символа с отрицательным кодом.